# Why I am getting the error?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, runtime-error

```
 import java.util.*;
public class Nostalgia {
    static ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
    static int array[] ={6,3,6,2,3};
    //static int num;
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    arr.set(0, 8);
    arr.set(1, 4);
    arr.set(3, 6);
    arr.set(2, 9);
    arr.set(4, 7);
    arr.set(5, 1);


    System.out.print(3+" :"+arr.get(3));

}
}
```

I am getting this error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
>     at Nostalgia.main(Nostalgia.java:9)

I am trying to put some values in my List and display a value at a certain index.

Comment: Did you search for what `IndexOutOfBoundsException` means?

Comment: Stupid me. thanks  "ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ"  and  "Eran".

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that you are calling SET(x,y) on an empty list, and set does [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-):

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element

but the set method is actually a replacing operation... how can java replace an element that doesnt exist..

instead of set elements on an empty list:

```
arr.set(0, 8);
arr.set(1, 4);
arr.set(3, 6);
```

you should ADD them to the list

```
arr.add(0, 8);
arr.add(1, 4);
```

**BUT be careful**, you can not add an element beyond the actual size of the list!

Comment: Could also use `add(Object)`, without the index, to append.

Comment: Also I learned that adding a value to an index before adding to the previous index gives error. maybe because lists nodes are linked with each other.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList`s are initialized to empty lists (unless you use the constructor that takes a source `Collection`). `new ArrayList<Integer>(5)` doesn't create a list of 5 elements, it creates an empty list with initial capacity of 5 (which means the length of the initial backing array is 5).

`set` only works if the index you are trying to update the value at already has a previous value.

Therefore you should be using `add`. And you don't have to supply an index to `add`.

Comment: Thanks I was stuck in it for an hour.